# Pass arguments that extends from same abstract class to function

Tags: java, oop

I finished some exercise but I wanted to optimize it a little bit.
I have two classes name "U1" and "U2", both extend the same abstract class called "Rocket" and I have two functions called "loadU1" and "loadU2" that returns ArrayList (U1 or U2) and i wanted to optimize it to one function without success. I tried the  generic type, but I cant figure out how should I know which type to return or cast to. Does it possible?
Note: I didn't share some code that I have tried because I got no idea where should I start even (JAVA Newbie).

This is the strcture of the classes:

```
public class U1 extends Rocket {}

public class U2 extend Rocket {}

abstract class Rocket implements SpaceShip {}
```

These are the current functions:

```
public ArrayList<U1> loadU1(ArrayList<Item> items) {
    ArrayList<U1> u1Rockets = new ArrayList<>();

    return u1Rockets;
}

public ArrayList<U2> loadU2(ArrayList<Item> items) {
    ArrayList<U2> u2Rockets = new ArrayList<>();

    return u2Rockets;
}
```

Comment: Try `List<? extends Rocket>`.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. What is the point of having `ArrayList<Item> items` parameter in both methods if it is never used by them? Or what is the point of creating local variable if you immediately return its value? For now both methods can be rewritten as `{ return new ArrayList<>(); }`. What is the main goal here? Is it perhaps to be able to do something like `ArrayList<U1> u1ArrayList = loadRockets(); ArrayList<U2> u2ArrayList = loadRockets();`? If yes why not write `ArrayList<U1> u1ArrayList = new ArrayList<>(); ArrayList<U2> u2ArrayList = new ArrayList<>();`?

Comment: Solution from accepted answer can be rewritten as `public <T extends Rocket> List<T> load() {return new ArrayList<>(); }` (since it doesn't use `items` and `rockets` variables). It can be used like `List<U1> u1Rockets = load();` *BUT* that would be effectively same as writing `List<U1> u1Rockets = new ArrayList<>();` which defeats purpose of having such method. IMO question requires more details/clarity to be properly understood and found by people having same problem you are facing (which is main goal of this site).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
public <T extends Rocket> List<T> load(List<Item> items) {
    List<T> rockets = new ArrayList<>();

    return rockets;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I misunderstand question. This is better option.